# How to format plain Null ('\0') character for query string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, null

For an macOS system uninstall command, need to insert and format the command with plain null ('\0') character.

However, python formatter convert that null character string into it's own hex format **'\x00'** which is in-correct for the requirement

How do I format following uninstall command in python

`Command = 'pkgutil --only-dirs --files <your-package-id> | tail -r | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -n 1 -0 sudo rmdir'`

Tried following method but not working as expected

`PACKAGE_ID = 'com.abcd.bdr'`

`TR_COMMAND = 'tr \'\n\' \'\0\''`

`command = u'pkgutil --only-dirs --files {} | tail -r | {} | xargs -n 1 -0 sudo rm -rif'.format(PACKAGE_ID, TR_COMMAND)`

`prog = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
_outs, _errs = prog.communicate(b'')`

Python converts the Null character '\0' string to '\x00' which is not correct for me

Expected result was :
`Command = 'pkgutil --only-dirs --files <your-package-id> | tail -r | tr '\n' **'\0'** | xargs -n 1 -0 sudo rmdir'`

But python complier gives :
`Command = 'pkgutil --only-dirs --files <your-package-id> | tail -r | tr '\n' '**\x00'** | xargs -n 1 -0 sudo rmdir'`

Comment: Have you tried  `TR_COMMAND = 'tr \'\\n\' \'\\0\''` instead?

Comment: Yes bkyada, I tried that already it gives output as " tr '\n' '\\0' " - it adds additional '\' to the string format. What you think how do I remove additional '\' character in this

Comment: I have tried `'tr \'\\n\' \'\0\''` in `Python2` and `Python3` and I am getting `pkgutil --only-dirs --files com.abcd.bdr | tail -r | tr '\n' '' | xargs -n 1 -0 sudo rm -rif` after using `.format ` statement.

Comment: Try `TR_COMMAND ='tr \'\\n\' \'\x00\''` in case if it is reading `\0` it as an octal literal

Comment: Tried above comment bkyada, it's not working its gives output as TR_COMMAND = ' tr '\\n' '\x00' '

Comment: The `'\x00'` is the string representation for a string with a single null-byte. That's what python shows when you drop the variable into a REPL like the interactive python prompt - maybe you just need to `print` your string to see what you expect.